# How to find the correct ‘onClick’ script to open side menu

Tags: woocommerce, mobile, menu, onclick

I use the [WP Mobile Menu](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mobile-menu/) plugin to create a slideout left panel menu in my WooCommerce store, and would like to use a [WP Bottom Menu](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-bottom-menu/) item to open this WP Mobile Menu slideout left panel menu.

The WP Bottom Menu plugin allows you to add custom JavaScript for any menu item in an 'onClick' section.

How can I find the correct script to place in the onClick section to activate the WP Mobile Menu button function?

I also use WPC Fly Cart for WooCommerce for a slideout right panel cart, and the script was quite easy to find `woofc_toggle_cart();` but I can't for the life of me work out the correct script for WP Mobile Menu.

If you have any idea of the script I should use, or any suggestion on what I might be looking for, please let me know.

I appreciate the help!